# Sum of subtractions using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

everyone.

I've faced a task, that looked pretty simple to me, but I spend like 4 hours and left with nothing. So, let's assume we have simple list of integers like

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I want to get sum of subtractions for each element - for this list, it would be equal to 4 -> (2 - 1) + (3 - 2)... and so on.

To avoid answers with range, list may look like this:

`[5, 12, 16, 25, 25, 48]`

It's always growing, but not with the same range between.

Using simple *for* it's not hard to get something like:

```
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < lst.size(); i++) {
        result += lst.get(i) - lst.get(i-1);
    }
```

But I'm feeling myself utterly stupid when I'm trying to solve this case using streams.

Is this actually possible?

Comment: What you are calculating is just `lst.get(lst.size()-1) - lst.get(0)` — the last element minus the first.

Comment: Streams are designed for processing items one at a time. You want to process items and include the context of their neighbours. It's not impossible to accomplish with streams but equally there's no reason to use them.

Comment: @Michael If the list is `[1,2,3,4,1]` then the result is 0, which is still the last element minus the first.

Comment: @Michael (2-1) + (3-2) + (4-3) + (1-4) is equal to 0, so khelwood's solution still works

Comment: @khelwood So it is. Bad maths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of Integers like this : `[ n0, n1, n2, ... , nM, nN ]`, what you're doing is :

1. Create list `[(n1 - n0), (n2 - n1), (n3 - n2), ..., (nN - nM)]`.
2. Sum that list : `X = (n1 - n0) + (n2 - n1) + (n3 - n2) + ... + (nN - nM)`.
   Which is rigourously the same (just swapped the inside of parenthesises as they don't matter) as `X = (-n0) + (n1 - n1) + (n2 - n2) + ... + (nM - nM) + nN ]`.

Which is (as others pointed out) `X = nN - n0`. **No matter what is inside your list** (except *null*).

Thus, `lst.get(lst.size()-1) - lst.get(0)` is, by far, the best answer.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
int result = IntStream.range(1, lst.size())  // creates a stream of indexes from 1 to lst.size()
        .map(i -> lst.get(i) - lst.get(i-1)) // maps the new value into a new stream
        .sum();                              // sums it up
```

Comment: It's basically just a weird looking for loop.

Comment: I've edited the question with another example of a list.

Comment: @AlbertZoich my example still works fine, because the intStream generated holds only the indices